# how to record audio in matlab online?

Tags: matlab

i want to record voice from mic in MATLAB. but i don't want to decide when to stop the recording upfront, so i look for a way to stop while recording.

i've tried the follow code:

```
clc
clear
close all

r = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 1);
record(r);     % speak into microphone...
pause(r);
p = play(r);   % listen
resume(r);     % speak again
stop(r);
p = play(r);   % listen to complete recording
mySpeech = getaudiodata(r, 'int16'); % get data as int16 array
```

but i got some errors:

```
??? Error using ==> audioplayer.audioplayer at 68
Recorder is empty.

Error in ==> audiorecorder.play at 28
player = audioplayer(obj);

Error in ==> record2 at 10
p = play(r);   % listen
```

if anyone can help me and explain to me why it dosen't work, i'll be very thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have constant time of recording consider calling these functions manually (I assume that you have audiorecorder object 'r'):

```
record(r);
```

to start recording

```
stop(r);
```

to stop recording (whenever you want)

```
play(r);
```

to play recorded sound

All comands have to be called manually (from Matlab Command Window) because in one script there is very short time between start and pause recording and nothing is recorded.
and one more thing - your code works fine in my environment - no errors at all

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that no time passes between `record` and `pause`, nothing is recorded. Use `record` or `recordblocking` with a duration parameter set.